# Distinct dict keys from array of dict

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project using MongoDB. I have so far managed to upload documents to the database. Records looks like

```
doc1 = {'customer_id': 1,
    'order': "[{'item': 123, 'unit_price': 2.0}, \
                  {'item': 124, 'unit_price': 2.5}]"}
doc2 = {'customer_id': 2,
    'order': "[{'item': 123, 'unit_price': 2.0}, \
                  {'item': 126, 'unit_price': 1.5}]"}

collection.insert(doc1)
collection.insert(doc2)
```

I would like to find distinct items from the collection. My attempt so far

```
 db.collection.distinct("order.item")
```

Expected output:

```
[123,124,126]
```

This does not quite work since `order` is an array. I am looking for some way to `unnest` the array to get distinct item numbers. Eventually, I would like to get the count of those distinct items. Thanks for your help!

Comment: your sample documents returns distinct items for the query, can you post the expected output?

Comment: @Saravana Ah, I see my issue. Checked the records again and the list is a string! Looks like I will have to pre-process documents beforehand. Thanks for the pointer. I made some changes to the question, along with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does return distinct for nested items from an array of objects:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#return-distinct-values-for-an-embedded-field

In your case  `db.collection.distinct("order.item")` should return array of distinct items from orders collection